# Camel File Poller of a Mounted CIFS

Tags: apache-camel

We're experiencing a strange problem.

We have a file component monitoring a folder.  This works perfectly if the path is either

a) myrelativepath - which is relative to the Karaf installation where the camel route is run; or 
b) /tst/mypath - which reads from a folder from the root

If I set log level to DEBUG I see the logs of it polling based on my interval.

However, if I set the path to be:
/mnt/windowsshare - which is a mounted windows share.

I get nothing in the logs, I don't see the poll, and it doesn't pick up any files. apparently the route is started though.

Interestingly, I have another camel route which writes a file to that location (a subfolder called inbound) and it writes file with no problem.

Any ideas?

I can get perhaps more logs tomorrow, but this is only happening in this environment where we have a windows share.  And the share seems to be fine.

For testing we have run Camel as root and as root on the commandline we have tested reading the files (via vi) and all is ok.

Any suggestions for things to look at?

Comment: This appears to be related to how many files we are polling and not a CIFS issue (although it was only a guess). We are monitoring a large folder structure with several archive folders nested within (a legacy constraint we can't change).  The antInclude and antExclude, are working but still doesnt stop the File component being saturated by large volumes.  A top level folder with 50k files across subdirectories is ok.  But at 130k the FileConsumer just hangs.  We're looking to see what contributes to this i.e. the number of files passing include & exclude rules, or just total files.

Comment: Doesn't like having 1000s of files in an antExclude path. Interestingly there is a limit. 80k odd is fine, and it will poll in a few seconds. Add 50ish more, and the poll takes over a minute. Very odd. It's like a cliff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically make sure you don't have too many files in the antexlcude...polling is logarithmic and a fraction more makes polling very slow.

Needs more code analysis and VM introspection to understand why.